# How to Catch Parameter from a Form without serialize

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

thanks for your time and your knowledge !

So here is my question, I'm trying to POST multiple strings with AJAX without serializing them in only one data bloc. I want to do that because my php on server side react to them individualy.

Here is the server side:

```html
<?php
$subjectPrefix = '[Contact via le Site]';
$emailTo = 'kokolesinge@gmail.com';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $name    = stripslashes(trim($_POST['form-name']));
    $email   = stripslashes(trim($_POST['form-email']));
    $subject = stripslashes(trim($_POST['form-subject']));
    $message = stripslashes(trim($_POST['form-message']));
    $pattern  = '/[\r\n]|Content-Type:|Bcc:|Cc:/i';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $name) || preg_match($pattern, $email) || preg_match($pattern, $subject)) {
        die("Header injection detected");
    }
    $emailIsValid = preg_match('/^[^0-9][A-z0-9._%+-]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/', $email);
    if($name && $email && $emailIsValid && $subject && $message){
        $subject = "$subjectPrefix $subject";
        $body = "Nom: $name <br /> Email: $email <br /> Message: $message";
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.1' . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "From: $name <$email>" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Return-Path: $emailTo" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $emailSent = true;
    } else {
        $hasError = true;
    }
}
?>
```

So as you see the 4 variables for which I'm looking are form-name, form-email, form subject, form-message. Those strings come from a form which is this one:

```html
<div id="contact" class="contact">
  <div class="container">
<?php if(!empty($emailSent)): ?>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="alert alert-success text-center">Votre message a ete envoye avec succes.</div>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
<?php if(!empty($hasError)): ?>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4">
      <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Un erreur s'est produite, essayer a nouveau.</div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
        <input type="text"  name="form-name" placeholder="Nom" />
        <input type="email"  name="form-email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="text" name="form-subject" placeholder="Objet" />
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <textarea  rows="3"  name="form-message" placeholder="Message" /></textarea>
        <div class="sub">
          <button id="envoyer" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Envoyer</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

So my problem is that I want to catch those 4variables from my form post them using AJAX and then recepting them. For now I'm just trying to show on of this parameter in an alertbox, but it's not working and I am only able to display them beeing serialized with this JQuery script:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#envoyer").click(function(){
    alert($('#contact-form').serialize());
/*
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'index.php',
      data: {form-name : form-name, form-email : form-email, form-subject : form-subject, form-message : form-message}
      success: function(data)
      {
        alert("success!");
      }
    });
*/
  });
});
</script>
```

So this last snippet is the one I need help on, I would like to be able to catch those parameters from my form and simply display them in an alertbox for now (I would be able to post them with AJAX after, displayig them is the first step to be sure it's working well).

So again thanks for you time and I hope I have been clear about my question, thanks ! :)

Comment: So what happens, does the alert show at all, is the content not serialized ?

Comment: It's working fine here... I cannot reproduce your issue.